# Sortable list not working on ipad

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make sortable list on Ipad. I used the following [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sidonaldson/PeS2D/).
But it doesn't work i just can scroll the whole page instead of moving components of the list.
Please help

Comment: The jsfiddle you linked to seems to work fine, if the problem is in your code then it's going to be kinda difficult for anyone to help you without seeing any of it.

Comment: We use [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) for this. It's transparent and (mostly) seamless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the documentation from Apple on [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) which talks about event handling. Essentially you'll have to prevent the default behavior of dragging.

```
function touchMove(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    curX = event.targetTouches[0].pageX - startX;
    curY = event.targetTouches[0].pageY - startY;
    event.targetTouches[0].target.style.webkitTransform =
        'translate(' + curX + 'px, ' + curY + 'px)';
}
```